# Bibliotecas em CMake como submodule em projeto

Tags: c++, cmake, library

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em C++ onde faço uso de umas bibliotecas que produzi anteriormente, o problema que não sei como importa-las neste meu novo projeto sem colocar o caminho completo no include e adicionar todos os arquivos no cmake do meu projeto. 

O projeto completo está disponível no [Github](https://github.com/TigreFramework/FrameWork), ele possui uma pasta chamada `vendor` que é onde pretendo colocar todas as dependencias, mas preciso saber primeiro como adiciona-las no cmake.


Como gostaria de colocar no include: `#include "Network/Socket.h"`


O Arquivo `main.cpp` compila normalmente pois não precisa de nenhuma dependência do `vendor` já o `server.cpp` precisa do `Network` por isso gera um erro, e se eu for adicionar manualmente no CMake e no include todas as bibliotecas fica inviável, pois a biblioteca `String` possui inúmeros arquivos por causa do RSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente você deve estar se referindo sobre `target_include_directories` para incluir as headers e `target_link_libraries` para incluir as referencias das bibliotecas.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, mas em vês de ```target_include_directories``` eu usei o ```include_directories``` na ```pasta vendor``` assim todas as bibliotecas são incluídas.